# Attribute disappeared after setting to memcache?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, pickle

I am using Appengine's memcache.

I have a class, `TaskGroup`, which I will be setting an attribute dynamically.

```
from mempo.models import Task, Order, TaskAction, TaskGroup
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import memcache

tg = TaskGroup.query().fetch(1)[0]
print 1, tg 
setattr(tg, TaskGroup.JSON_TASKS_KEY, {'hello': 'world'})
print 2, getattr(tg, TaskGroup.JSON_TASKS_KEY)

KEY = 'mc_key'
memcache.delete(KEY)
memcache.set(KEY, tg)

tg2 = memcache.get(KEY)
print 3, getattr(tg2, TaskGroup.JSON_TASKS_KEY)
```

This is the output from the interactive console:

```
1 TaskGroup(key=Key('TaskGroup', 4504974016905216), order=Key('Order', 5491235947020288), order_entry_serial=u'fc5766b2bbad4905be8753f9a6300009', orphaned=False, state=TaskGroupState(UNSTARTED, 10))
2 {'hello': 'world'}
3Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vng/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 216, in handle_interactive_request
    exec(compiled_code, self._command_globals)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TaskGroup' object has no attribute 'json_tasks'
```

AFAIK, pickle dumps attributes set dynamically as well:

```
class Foo():
    pass

f = Foo()

pickle.dumps(f)
Out[4]: '(i__main__\nFoo\np0\n(dp1\nb.'

In [5]: setattr(f, 'hello', 'world')

In [6]: pickle.dumps(f)
Out[6]: "(i__main__\nFoo\np0\n(dp1\nS'hello'\np2\nS'world'\np3\nsb."
```

Can someone tell me why appengine's memcache is not pickling my JSON_TASKS_KEY attribute?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with memcache -- As far as I can tell, TaskGroup.JSON_TASKS_KEY never gets put to memcache... But I certainly have no idea why it would be disappearing ...

Comment: Can you show me the code of the attribute being set and how do you queue the task?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how ndb handles pickling. ndb.Model implements `__getstate__`, which allows it to overwrited how it is pickled. In particular, ndb handles it by converting to it's internal serialized representation, then encoding that. This internal representation only stores the properties it knows about.

If you want to use dynamic attributes with ndb, you should have your models extend `ndb.Expando` instead of `ndb.Model`.